# Predict a continuous data without a linear shape on data points

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataset like that

[image]

I want to predict the financial loss given the incident type. This is a brief visualisation
[image]

As the financial loss is a continuous data, I know that I cant do a linear regression because the data points do not have a linear shape. Is there a model that I can predict the loss given this shape of data points?

I tried Linear Regression and the score is 0.11. Is there something wrong?

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc=enc.fit_transform(df2[['Incident Type']])
enc  # [error,hacking,malware,misuse,social]
X = enc
Y = df2['Financial Loss']
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,Y)

print('Loss prediction for error: {}'.format(model.predict([[1,0,0,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for hacking: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,1,0,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for malware: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,1,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for misuse: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,0,1,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for social: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,0,0,1]])))
Loss prediction for error: [5485962.64285715]
Loss prediction for hacking: [34497821.87500001]
Loss prediction for malware: [345000.00000001]
Loss prediction for misuse: [3069580.7830769]
Loss prediction for social: [21267679.99999998]

model.score(X,Y)
0.11545420819598817
```

Comment: Is incident type the only feature in your dataset?

Comment: I have employee count( 6 different integers) and year of the incident

Comment: If you just use the incident type, there is a great deal of variability, so the high loss values are not surprising. If you also want to consider, the other variables, then you have a more complicated problem that could involve interactions and nonlinearity, and the random forest suggestion might be a good one. If you only want to consider the incident type, I think you're stuck regressing on the incident type (which you appear to have implemented correctly), knowing that you will not be able to pin down the financial loss in a tight range. // You might be interested in a different GLM choice.

Comment: @Dave So the reason for the low score is due to the wide range of the y variable value? I was assuming that low model score means something is done wrongly.

Comment: It means, loosely speaking, that a typical deviation from the mean is about what the loss value is. You're pinning down the financial loss to within a few hundred-thousand to a few million dollars. For losses that can exceed \$100 million, that does not sound too bad.

Comment: Does implementing train/test or pipeline helps with the accuracy for this case? There are only 80 data points

Comment: You're not going to have overfitting issues with this kind of regression. I do not see how any kind of holdout data would help. // What do you mean by a pipeline?

Comment: Chaining the data preprocessing and model training in a pipeline for cross validating. Is it useful anywhere here?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very similar to this [stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/predicting-a-continuous-output-in-a-dataset-with-categories?rq=1) where they discuss this is possible using a Random Forest model. You would just need to one-hot encode your categorical variables into dummy variables. To do this, you can read and follow this [primer here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-hot-encoding-for-categorical-data/), where it details one-hot encoding and why it would be relevant for your dataset. In short, since the categories you have displayed show no rank or order, we can say they are nominal, hence why you will need to one-hot encode them.

Comment: Unless there is a way for the categories to interact (it appears they cannot), then I cannot see how a random forest would improve on an ANOVA-style linear regression on the categories themselves, such as `lm(financial_loss ~ as.factor(incident_type))` in R. Perhaps an important question to ask the OP is if an incident can be hacking and misuse (for example).

Comment: @Dave No, each incident is only under 1 type

Comment: Do you have additional predictor variables? @Fuustack

Comment: @Dave I edited the post, take a look

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by predicting the financial loss. Since you mention linear regression, I will assume that you want to know the expected loss, given the type of incident.

In that case, linear regression absolutely applies, just on the categories encoded as dummy variables.$^{\dagger}$ Thus, you have five predictor variables:

1. Was it hacking?
2. Was it error?
3. Was it misuse?
4. Was it social?
5. Was it malware?

Each of these variables is either no (encoded as $0$) or yes (encoded as $1$).

You then do the linear regression on the five binary variables. In R, this would be coded either explicitly by transforming your categorical variable into five binary variables or by regressing on the incident type as a "factor" variable, via `lm(financial_loss ~ as.factor(incident_type))`. Python will have some equivalent code.

$^{\dagger}$It is common to let one of the categories be the intercept. I will ignore that here. The difference is subtle and really applicable to inference rather than prediction. You will be able to make the same predictions either way.

Comment: Something worth considering is the skewness in your groups. OLS works, in some sense, for skewed groups (Gauss-Markov theorem does not require normality), but you might have better luck modeling with skewed distributions like gamma distributions by using a different kind of generalized linear model, again using the group as a factor variable. You might have to implement this in `statsmodels` instead of `sklearn` (but maybe not). And if you don't know what a GLM is: 1) Perhaps OLS is the best option, given your background 2) They're useful and worth learning.